# Не проходит авторизация API VK JAVA

Tags: java, vkontakte-api

При попытке запуска, получаю ошибку:

```
Caused by: 
com.vk.api.sdk.exceptions.ClientException: 
Internal API server error. Wrong status code: 401. 
Content: 
{"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"Code is invalid or expired."}
```

Сначала думал, code потерял валидность.
Запросил снова, но проблема осталась.

Запрашивал так:

https://oauth.vk.com/authorize?client_id=41264482&display=page&redirect_uri=https://oauth.vk.com/blank.html&scope=wall,offline&response_type=code&v=5.131

Подскажите пожалуйста, где я ошибся?

```
package reversbot.services;


import com.vk.api.sdk.client.TransportClient;
import com.vk.api.sdk.client.VkApiClient;
import com.vk.api.sdk.client.actors.UserActor;
import com.vk.api.sdk.exceptions.ApiException;
import com.vk.api.sdk.exceptions.ClientException;
import com.vk.api.sdk.httpclient.HttpTransportClient;
import com.vk.api.sdk.objects.UserAuthResponse;
import com.vk.api.sdk.objects.wall.GetFilter;
import com.vk.api.sdk.objects.wall.responses.GetResponse;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Scheduled;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;

@Service
public class VkBot {

    @Value("${APP_ID}")
    int APP_ID;

    @Value("${CLIENT_SECRET}")
    String CLIENT_SECRET;

    @Value("${REDIRECT_URI}")
    String REDIRECT_URI;

    @Value("${code}")
    String code;

    @Scheduled(fixedDelay = 5000)
    @PostConstruct
    public void vkb() throws ClientException, ApiException {

        TransportClient transportClient = new HttpTransportClient();
        VkApiClient vk = new VkApiClient(transportClient);
        UserAuthResponse authResponse = vk.oAuth()
                .userAuthorizationCodeFlow(APP_ID, CLIENT_SECRET, REDIRECT_URI, code)
                .execute();

        UserActor actor = new UserActor(authResponse.getUserId(), authResponse.getAccessToken());

        GetResponse getResponse = vk.wall().get(actor)
                .ownerId(1)
                .count(100)
                .offset(5)
                .filter(GetFilter.valueOf("all"))
                .execute();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Задача решилась по другому. Авторизация "Implicit Flow для получения ключа доступа пользователя" решила мою проблему.

```
    package reversbot.services;


import com.vk.api.sdk.client.TransportClient;
import com.vk.api.sdk.client.VkApiClient;
import com.vk.api.sdk.client.actors.UserActor;
import com.vk.api.sdk.exceptions.ApiException;
import com.vk.api.sdk.exceptions.ClientException;
import com.vk.api.sdk.httpclient.HttpTransportClient;
import com.vk.api.sdk.objects.wall.responses.GetResponse;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Scheduled;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;


@Service

public class VkBot {

    @Value("${APP_ID}")
    int APP_ID;

    @Value("${access_token}")
    String access_token;



//    @Scheduled(fixedDelay = 5000)
    @PostConstruct
    public void vkb() throws ClientException, ApiException {

        TransportClient transportClient = new HttpTransportClient();
        VkApiClient vk = new VkApiClient(transportClient);


        UserActor actor = new UserActor(APP_ID, access_token);

        GetResponse getResponse = vk.wall().get(actor)
                .ownerId(-234148536)
                .count(1)
                .offset(5)
                .execute();


        System.out.println("........FROM HERE.........");
        System.out.println(getResponse);
        System.out.println(".........HERE........");
    }

}
```

[image: work program]